# Source File Compiling and Command

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to programming and was able to compile the following source code in C++ using Visual Studio, but when I put the command that came with the source file **foo < RTP300.cfg > text.cfg** nothing happens. This command is supposed to generate a text file from a router configuration file. Where should the RTP300.cfg file that the command is pointing to be located? Any other info that can help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int decode(unsigned char);

int
decode(unsigned char ch)
{
  ch = ~((ch << 2) | ((ch & 0xC0) >> 6));
  if (ch) {
    if (isprint(ch)) {
      return ch;
    } else {
      return ' ';
    }
  }
  return '\n';
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int  ch;
  FILE *fp;

  if (argc < 2) {
    fp = stdin;
   } else {
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error:  Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  while (EOF != (ch =fgetc(fp))) {
    fputc(decode(ch), stdout);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `RTP300.cfg` should be present in the current working directory. Which in your case is likely the same directory where `foo` executable is located.

Comment: in order to use the command you give the file must be in the same directory as the 'foo' binary

Comment: Also, note that you must give the command in cmd.exe for that command to work. Those are not parameters to the program, they redirect standard input and output. Not sure if you can do it in Visual Studio, or if you must do it from actual command prompt (or with a shortcut or .bat file).

Comment: @ Igor- by foo executable, I assume you mean the compiled exe file, right? Tried that without success.

Comment: @pm100- I do not see a foo binary in the project folder.

Comment: @hyde- I have used cmd to run the command as stated, but to no avail.

Comment: In visual studio you can put any arguments to the program in project properties under debugging > command arguments. If you do this, then you should have the files in the same directory as your project. If you want to run it from command line, the executable is inside either debug or release under solution directory. Other way is to `cd` to where you have the `cfg` file and then direct the command line to the executable: `"c:\my VS projects\solution1\Release\foo.exe" < bar.cfg > foobar.cfg`

Comment: Triple_r - Executable is inside Debug and it does not let me cd to where the file is at. Not sure why. Also, in the command line at the end of previous post do I need to change anything? Thanks!

Comment: RTP300.cfg & exe file in same folder. Can someone please take a look at source code and advise if command -foo < RTP300.cfg > text.cfg- should work or if something needs to be changed? when I tried Triple_r command (C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\router C++\foo.exe" < RTP300.cfg > text.cfg) it says "it is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or hatch file". When I removed the .exe after foo (C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\router C++\foo < RTP300.cfg > text.cfg), it said "the system cannot find the file specified". Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Getting a little closer now! When I run the command -foo < RTP300.cfg > text.cfg- in the folder, it now says "foo" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. However, it generates an empty text file (0 byte) in the folder. It does the same thing with using foo.exe instead in the command line or using the command -foo.exe" < bar.cfg > foobar.cfg-. Any HELP to fix the invoke command would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!